# Sentences in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm doing exercise of translating following sentences into FOL in Language of $L_{_{_{{EQ}}}}$, where there are no non-logical symbols. The only symbol is $=$. Are the following correct?

$1$. There are at least two individuals

$\exists x_1 \exists x_2[\lnot(x_1=x_2)\land \forall x_3 \left((x_3=x_2)\lor (x_3=x_1)\lor(\lnot(x_3=x_1)\land \lnot(x_3=x_2))\right)].$

$2$. There are at most two individuals

$\forall x_1 \forall x_2 [(\lnot(x_1=x_2)\lor (x_1=x_2))\land \forall x_3 ((x_3=x_1)\lor (x_3=x_2))]$.

$3$. There are exactly three individuals

$\exists x_1,x_2,x_3 [\lnot(x_1=x_2)\land \lnot(x_1=x_3)\land \lnot(x_2=x_3) \land \forall x_4\left( (x_4=x_1)\lor (x_4=x_2) \lor(x_4=x_3) \right).$

$4$. For any two individuals there is another individual distinct from both of them,

I got two sentences here:

$(i) \quad \forall x_1,x_2 [\lnot (x_1=x_2)\implies \exists x_3(\lnot(x_3=x_1)\land \lnot(x_3=x_2))],$

$(ii)\quad \forall x_1 \forall x_2 \exists x_3 [\lnot(x_1=x_2)\land \lnot (x_1=x_3)\land \lnot (x_2=x_3)]$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @lemontree Are these translations correct?

Comment: For "at least" it is enough $\exists x_1 \exists x_2 \lnot (x_1 = x_2)$

Comment: For "at most" $∃x_1∃x_2[∀x_3((x_3=x_2)∨(x_3=x_1))]$

Comment: "Exactly two" is $∃x_1∃x_2[¬(x_1=x_2) \land ∀x_3((x_3=x_2) ∨ (x_3=x_1))]$. And so on.